# Submiting parsed content into ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to upload  files(.txt, .pdf) in Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch receives only content in json format. Is there any way that I send parsed content(.pdf or .txt to String) directly or I have to parse String into json document to send it to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send JSON when indexing a Document, so basically, a base64 encoded version of the file in some field of that JSON will do just fine. If you do not wish to search inside this content, then all you have to do is disabling indexing on that "binary data" field (option `index:false` in your mapping).

If you wish to send a PDF file and have the textual content extracted and indexed / searchable, you should have a look at the [Ingest Attachment Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helps. I have a follow-up question. "so basically, a base64 encoded version of the file in some field of that JSON will do just fine", why I need to have a base64 encoded version and not the content of file directly in JSON to be sent to Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler for your use case.
Basically, This crawler helps to index binary documents such as PDF, Open Office, MS Office and will give you following feature

- Local file system (or a mounted drive) crawling and index new files,
  update existing ones and removes old ones.
- Remote file system over SSH crawling.
- REST interface to let you "upload" your binary documents to
  elasticsearch.